# Getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) in ubutnu16 while running apt-get install... command

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, apt-get

Hi I am getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error message in Ubuntu 16, whenever I do any installation like

sudo apt-get install default-jre

sudo apt-get install ns2

Comment: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is your friend! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because the list of packages was very long, I solved it with this.

```
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

[reboot the system]

apt-get update
```

that´s it. 
PD: you must to be root or use `sudo`.